# Infragistics XamDatagrid - prevent control from being instantiated when not visible

Tags: wpf, xaml, infragistics

We've got an Infragistics XamDatagrid with a column that contains an image.

This image can be visible or not depending on a ViewModel property. When it is visible, if you hover over, a popup is displayed. Please see below the XAML for this column.

```
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataPresenter:CellValuePresenter}">
                <Border Background="{StaticResource FrozenColumnBrush}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Image x:Name="BarrierImage"
                               Grid.Row="0"
                     Height="16" Width="16"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     Source="../Images/lock_16.ico"
                     Visibility="{Binding DataItem.IsBarrierEvent, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" >
                        </Image>
                        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding DataItem.IsBarrierEvent, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" >
                        <Popup
                               Name="BarrierPopup"
                               AllowsTransparency="True"
                               PopupAnimation="Fade"
                               HorizontalOffset="-35"
                               VerticalOffset="0"
                               Behaviors:OpenPopupWhenTooltipOpening.Control="{Binding ElementName=BarrierImage}"
                               >
                            <Views:BarrierView DataContext="{Binding DataItem.Barriers}"/>
                        </Popup>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

The problem is that we get 200 rows, but only one has IsBarrierEvent = true, therefore there's only one image and only one popup will be displayed when hovering. But it turns out that WPF creates a BarrierView control for each row. We've noticed that when using dotTrace to investigate performance issues.

Is there any way to prevent this non-visible controls to be created? We've tried to also bind the viewmodel property to the main border visibility, but they're still being created.

Thanks.

P.S - I tried to paste in the XAML tags for the Style, but it wasn't properly displayed

Comment: which method of generation mode do you use? setting RecordContainerGenerationMode to Recycle your cellvaluepresenters will be created just for rows effectively displayed and reused when you scroll, otherwise i think you need to add it dynamically every time you need it

Comment: We're using "Recycle" mode. The point is that the control is created for all the visible rows, even though the column is not visible. Well, not the column itself but the content of the column.

Comment: Just to be clear, we have a column which can contain an image or not. When you hover over that image, you see a popup. We don't want the popup control to be instantiated for those rows where the image is not visible.

Comment: I can suggest to move this popup inside a trigger, this should create the popup only when trigger is activated

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you create your own custom control and move the Image, Popup, etc. into the template of that control. When you have elements defined in a template and that template is applied all of the elements within that template will be created so in this case when the CVP template is applied that means that Image, the Popup, the BarrierView, etc. will be created even if an ancestor element within the template is collapsed. However if you have a control in the template whose Visibility is Collapsed, the template of that control would not be applied until it is first measured which won't happen until the Visibility is Hidden or Visible.